# Is there a way to update every Github project when a dependency changes?

Tags: maven, github, gradle, pom.xml

We have quite a few projects, some using Maven and some using Gradle. They all live on Github and publish to a maven repository. When a project A changes from version x to x+1, I would like to update all projects B, C, and D with a dependency on A:x to version A:x+1 so that the builds for B, C, and D will kick off and either pass or fail. Are there any tools to be able to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: If these projects are so tightly integrated, why are they in different github repositories?

Comment: So that they can be separately versioned. Note that we MOSTLY would like them to be versioned in lock step, but we don't ALWAYS want them to be versioned in lock step. We would like the option of bu.ping all dependencies.

Comment: What about [dependabot](https://github.com/dependabot) ? to me the description looks the same as @JFabianMeier already asked. If they are so tightly coupled why having them in separate git repos. Can you explain what you mean by `lock step`... ? Apart from that you could check for the REST API of GitHub ..which could be used to do such things...